# Quickly losing a queen in style

Tags: problems, records, queens

I accidentally ran into this game again.

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "7"]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 Qf6 3. e5 Qf5 4. Bd3
```

What would be the fastest way to lose a queen by a direct attack on it (i.e. no pin, no discovered, no mate threats, etc.), when it has a maximum of 27 moves, but all 27 squares are attacked by the enemy? I estimate around 20 moves and very silly play. Avoid prematurely hanging the queen (or mate in 1) if possible.

Comment: Related: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73877/the-fastest-queen-trap-chess?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Treating the queen as a king, **31 plies** is done.

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "31"]

1. c4 d5 2. Qa4+ Nc6 3. d4 Bh3 4. g4 Rb8 5. Na3 b5 6. Nxb5 a6 7. Qxa6 Nxd4 8. Nxd4 f5 9. Nxf5 Nh6 10. Nxh6 dxc4 11. Be3 c3 12. f4 Qd7 13. Nxh3 Qd8 14. Nf2 Qd5 15. Rd1
```